# What if an acronym has no singular form?

Tags: acronyms

Do you need to add the s to an acronym that has no singular form?  Specifically, the Federal Motor Carrier Safety Regulations (FMCSR).

Comment: Doesn't the usage shown in any examples you find (and some should be given) give guidance?

Comment: I have seen it used both ways.   I was told initially that I should not use an s as there is no singular form, but I cannot find that this is a legitimate formatting rule or guidance.

Comment: The way an abbreviation is used is not dependent solely, or even primarily, on its long form. Whether you render it as a plural or not is largely a question of style, and as such, you should adhere to the discipline of your editor, publication, or organization, or in the absence of a house style, adopt a [style manual](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2579) appropriate to your tastes and audience and be consistent in its application.

Comment: I'd try to find how the FMCSA use it. It seems they invented it.